# Parse Json reponse into java objects with Gson

Tags: java, android, gson, ormlite, pojo

I have an issue to parse this json structure into its corresponding java objects:

```
[
{
preciosArtPK: {
                 codLista: 1,
                 codArticulo: 11348,
                 cansiVenta: 1,
                 fecVigencia: 1435781252000
               },
siglaVenta: "UN",
precioVenta: 0,
margenPct: 100,
codUsuario: 1,
vigente: "S",
nomModulo: "MIGRACION"
},
{
preciosArtPK: {
                 codLista: 1,
                 codArticulo: 15799,
                 cansiVenta: 1,
                 fecVigencia: 1435781252000
              },
siglaVenta: "UN",
precioVenta: 0,
margenPct: 100,
codUsuario: 1,
vigente: "S",
nomModulo: "MIGRACION"
}
]
```

I'm trying to insert into a table those datas and I use Gson to deserialize it and ORMLite to make the insert proccess. So, I have no problem with the components of the object but the inner object within I can't **(preciosArtPK: codLista, codArticulo, cansiVenta, fecVigencia)**. How could I manage this kind of json response in order to make the insert proccess easyly?

Following the POJO to deserialize this:

```
private List<PreciosArtPK> preciosArtPKList;

@DatabaseField(id = true, unique = true, columnName = PRECIOS_COD_LISTA)
private Integer codLista;

@DatabaseField(unique = true, columnName = PRECIOS_COD_ARTICULO)
private Integer codArticulo;

@DatabaseField(unique = true, columnName = PRECIOS_CANSI_VENTA)
private Integer cansiVenta;

@DatabaseField(unique = true, columnName = PRECIOS_FEC_VIGENCIA)
private Long fecVigencia;

@DatabaseField(columnName = PRECIOS_SIGLA_VENTA)
@SerializedName("siglaVenta")
private String siglaVenta;

@DatabaseField(columnName = PRECIOS_PRECIO_VENTA)
@SerializedName("precioVenta")
private Double precioVenta;

@DatabaseField(columnName = PRECIOS_MARGEN_PCT)
@SerializedName("margenPct")
private Float margenPct;

@DatabaseField(columnName = PRECIOS_COD_USUARIO)
@SerializedName("codUsuario")
private Integer codUsuario;

@DatabaseField(columnName = PRECIOS_VIGENTE)
@SerializedName("vigente")
private String vigente;

@DatabaseField(columnName = PRECIOS_NOM_MODULO)
@SerializedName("nomModulo")
private String nomModulo;
```

Any ideas how to handle this? I have a **"null"** response in every PK field within **"preciosArtPK"**. The notations above @serializeName are ORMLite's stuff. Please if you can help me I'll appreciate it a lot! thanks in advance.

Polite as usual,

Andy

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys since I don't have any response over here I'm in the obligation to close this with a solution for this issue that I had. It's very simple in fact is about just to include an instance of the inner object within the class, this is: I have **preciosArt.java**

```
public class preciosArt
{

@SerializedName("preciosArtPK")
private PreciosArtPK preciosArtPK;

@SerializedName("siglaVenta")
private String siglaVenta;

@SerializedName("precioVenta")
private Double precioVenta;

@SerializedName("margenPct")
private Float margenPct;

@SerializedName("codUsuario")
private Integer codUsuario;

@SerializedName("vigente")
private String vigente;

@SerializedName("nomModulo")
private String nomModulo;

}
```

Thing is just to include the inner object class and let gson do the work. Hope this help, any question I will be here!

Polite as usual,

Andy